# In Struts 2 redirectAction, can I pass dynamic complex objects without type conversion?

Tags: java, struts2

I am trying to pass an **ArrayList** of Objects from one action to another. I'd like to do something like this:

```
  <result name="success" type="redirectAction">
    <param name="actionName">myAction</param>
    <param name="parse">true</param>
    <s:iterator status="status" value="${myObjectsArrayList}">
        <param name="myObjectsArrayList[#status.index].var1" value=<s:property value="var1"/> />
    </s:iterator>
  </result>
```

Comment: you can store the values in session and can retrieve them in the other action else you can use `scope interceptor`

Comment: Your question is effectivly the same as the answer which follow: You probably don't want to redirect you want to chain (slight difference, but the difference is the answer)... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956603/action-redirect-in-struts-xml/4961005#4961005

Comment: @Quaternion: IMO i will not go for chaining until unless i have no other resource for solve this.

Comment: A redirect is just a new request--the only thing you can pass in a request is name/value pairs, and both are strings. So no, not the way you'd like to. I'm also pretty anti-chaining, the scope interceptor (or a generic flash interceptor) is the cleanest.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use "chain" result type, and it will keep all the parameters on the stack from the original action until the final result. One issue to mention is that you can't remap parameters with a "chain" result.