# How to forward result to another action in Struts2?

Tags: java, struts2

I have this action:

```
package com.test;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.Action;

public class TestAction implements Action{
    private String simpleParam;

    public String getSimpleParam() {
        return simpleParam;
    }

    public void setSimpleParam(String simpleParam) {
        this.simpleParam = simpleParam;
    }

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

When it's executed I want to invoke another action inside struts(e.g. not redirect) and pass to it simpleParam. SecondAction is:

```
package com.test;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.Action;

public class HelloAction implements Action {
    private String id;
    private String result;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        result = "result" + getId();
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

I saw working example when in struts.xml in result simply typed another action name and params and it worked. So I'm trying to do this:

```
<struts>
    <package name="main" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="test" class="com.test.TestAction">
            <result name="success">hello.action?id=${simpleParam}</result>
        </action>
        <action name="hello" class="com.test.HelloAction">
            <result>/hello.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

Idea totally sees this action but in browser I get 404 status. When I simply invoke hello.action from browser it works. Redirect also works. I also tried chain, but my param wasn't passed and it's not very convinient.
Am I doing it right? And if so what could be the cause of 404 status?

Comment: see this reference http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/redirect-result.html

Comment: I do not want to make redirect, e.g. not to send responce to browser with 302 status. I want to invoke another action inside struts.

Comment: than try this http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/redirect-action-result.html

Comment: It's the same redirect. Just more convinient for urls inside applications.

Comment: Use `redirectAction` result with parameters.

Comment: Difference between redirect and redirectAction is that in redirect I need to specify url by myself (localhost:8080/hello.action) and in redirectAction I need to just type name of action(hello) and struts will resolve it for me. But it's redirect(responce will be immideatly sent to browser with 302 status and then browser make second request to hello.action) and I want to forward(responce will be sent after the hello.action will be executed) my request and params to another action.

Comment: The actions are invoked by the client, i.e. browser and not the server. The server don't need to invoke an action because it can call a method.

Comment: @ArtemMalinko Maybe you are thinking chain: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956603/action-redirect-in-struts-xml/4961005#4961005

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this could be helpful: http://struts.apache.org/docs/action-chaining.html

```xml
<struts>
    <package name="main" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="test" class="com.test.TestAction">
            <result name="success" type="chain">hello</result>
        </action>
        <action name="hello" class="com.test.HelloAction">
            <result>/hello.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

to pass a parameter from one action to another you could use the HttpServletRequest
(http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/how-to-get-the-httpservletrequest-in-struts-2):

TestAction.java:

```java
package com.test;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.Action;

public class TestAction implements Action{
    private String simpleParam;

    public String getSimpleParam() {
        return simpleParam;
    }

    public void setSimpleParam(String simpleParam) {
        this.simpleParam = simpleParam;
    }

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
        request.setAttribute("id", simpleParam);
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

HelloAction.java:

```java
package com.test;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.Action;

public class HelloAction implements Action {
    private String id;
    private String result;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
        id = (String)request.getAttribute("id");

        result = "result" + getId();
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice to hear that I could help.

Answer (score -1):

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" id="WebApp_9" version="2.4">
  <display-name>Struts2 Application</display-name>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
            org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
        </filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: There is delete link under your post. Use it.

Answer (score -1):

web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" id="WebApp_9" version="2.4">
      <display-name>Struts2 Application</display-name>
      <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
                org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
            </filter-class>
      </filter>
      <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </filter-mapping>
      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>
    </web-app>
```

struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" id="WebApp_9" version="2.4">
  <display-name>Struts2 Application</display-name>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
            org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
        </filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<a href="viewrecords">View Records all</a>


</body>
</html>
```

edit.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>  

<b>id :</b> <s:property value="id"/> <br>
<b>name :</b> <s:property value="name"/> <br>
<b>salary :</b> <s:property value="salary"/> <br>
<s:textfield name="userid" label="phoneno" value="id"/>
```

UserAction.java

```
package com.action;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;



import com.model.User;

import com.userservice.UserService;


public class UserAction  {


    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int salary;
    private int phoneno;

    ArrayList<User> list=new ArrayList<User>();  

    public ArrayList<User> getList() {  
        return list;  
    }  
    public void setList(ArrayList<User> list) {  
        this.list = list;  
    }  
    public String execute(){  
      UserService service= new UserService();
    list=service.getdetails();

     return "success";  
    }  

    public String delete() {
        System.out.println("----------");



        return "success";
    }



    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    public int getPhoneno() {
        return phoneno;
    }
    public void setPhoneno(int phoneno) {
        this.phoneno = phoneno;
    }



}
```

UserService.java

```
package com.userservice;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.model.User;

public class UserService {
    ArrayList<User> list=new ArrayList<User>();


    public ArrayList<User> getdetails(){
    try{  
          Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  
          Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
            "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","oracletest","oracle");  

          PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from employee");  
          ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();  

          while(rs.next()){  
           User user=new User();  
           user.setId(rs.getInt(1));  
           user.setName(rs.getString(2));  
           user.setSalary(rs.getInt(3));  
           user.setPhoneno(rs.getInt(4));  

           list.add(user);  
           System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
          }  

          con.close();  
         }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

    return list;

    }

    public ArrayList<User> getList() {  
        return list;  
    }  
    public void setList(ArrayList<User> list) {  
        this.list = list;  
    } 
}
```

User.java

```
package com.model;

public class User {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int salary;
    private int phoneno;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    public int getPhoneno() {
        return phoneno;
    }
    public void setPhoneno(int phoneno) {
        this.phoneno = phoneno;
    }





}
```

welcome.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Struts2  Example</title>
</head>
<body>


<table>
<tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>salary</th>
    <th>phoneno</th>

</tr>
<s:iterator value="list" var="user">
    <tr>
        <td><s:property value="id"/> </td>
        <td><s:property value="name"/></td>
        <td><s:property value="salary"/></td>
        <td><s:property value="phoneno"/></td>
        <td><a href="<s:property value="delete"/>">edit</a></td>
        <td><a href="delete?id=<s:property value="id"/>&delete?name=<s:property value="name"/>">edit1</a></td>

    </tr> 
</s:iterator>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</html>
```

Comment: `FilterDispatcher` is deprecated. There is no struts.xml. It is just whole code dump not a real answer.